# How to unsubscribe to a callback for an event?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, we can add multiple functions to body's onload or a button's onclick. Is it possible to remove one of them, if we have the reference to the function ?

If possible, how to accomplish the same in jQuery and also plain JavaScript ?

Comment: [Yes it is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.removeEventListener).

Comment: Is it just a spec ? or it is supported by major browsers.

Comment: Did you read the page I linked to? It explains that. Also note that with jQuery you can use `.off()` or `.unbind()`.

Comment: Will it work even if the event was added without the use of addEvent Listener ?
If I add it to onclick of a button, then can I pass 'click' in removeEvent Listener for type for the same element.

Comment: No. See the answer by David for a solution to that.

Comment: ya I saw. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, but it depends on how the handler was attached in the first place.

If you used `addEventListener`, you can unbind using [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener).

If you used jQuery, you can use [`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/).

If you used `attachEvent`, you can use [`detachEvent()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If you used `onclick` or other `onxxx` functions, you can remove them by assigning `null`, f.ex `elem.onclick = null`.

Comment: Thanks. That means I need to be sure of how the event was added.

Comment: @AmoghTalpallikar yes. Using a library such as jQuery is by far the most convenient way to handle events cross-browser.